# Launch urxvt with python venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, urxvt

So I am trying to create a script that launches a `urxvt` terminal and sourcing a `venv/bin/activate` python env at the same time like this:

```sh
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp/venv;


urxvt -e sh -c "bash -c 'source /tmp/venv/bin/activate'; bash"
```

I cannot get it to work for some reason.

Does anyone know another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing it to this:

```sh
urxvt -e bash -c "source /tmp/venv/bin/activate; sh"
```

I am not sure why that works though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the command

```
urxvt -e sh -c "bash -c 'source /tmp/venv/bin/activate'; bash"
```

is that the 1st bash sources `activate` script and then exits so the second bash doesn't start in the venv being activated. Run the second bash inside `-c '…'` with the venv activated:

```
urxvt -e sh -c "exec bash -c 'source /tmp/venv/bin/activate && exec bash'"
```

PS. I love to use `exec` to *replace* the current shell instead of making it fork and wait. Saves a few processor cycles and a few bytes of memory.